# Is there a quick function that turns an entire matrix into a string?

Tags: javascript, string, function, matrix

I code in javascript and I often need to turn a matrix into a string, however when I do this I usually turn up with a useless scramble of invalid characters. I need a function in a format like this:
*string* = *function*(*matrix*)
Lets say that the matrix is [0, {a: 0, b: 1}, 1, [1, 2, 3], 0] It looks like this when I try to convert it to a string: 0,[object Object],1,1,2,3,0
I need the output to equal the input, does anybody have a solution?

Comment: How about `JSON.stringify()`?

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()` converts a JavaScript `object` into a string.

```js
var myObj = [0, {
  a: 0,
  b: 1
}, 1, [1, 2, 3], 0];

console.log(getString(myObj));

function getString(obj) {
return JSON.stringify(obj)
}
```

Comment: It serializes a JS object to a string.  JSON is always a string, and in this case is the final product, not the starting point, which is a JS array/object.

Comment: @Amy, JSON is a standard. Not a string.

Comment: It is a standard, yes, but that is incorrect.  JSON is a serialized JS object in string format.  If it is not a string, it is not JSON.  Your `myObj` is a JS object literal expression, *not* JSON.

Comment: Oh I see, I typed rushly, and didn't notice I said `JSON into a string`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to communicate. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try JSON.stringify()?

Read about it from MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify